# ValueError: Invalid parameter n_estimators for estimator LogisticRegression(random_state=42)

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, logistic-regression, hyperparameters, gridsearchcv

I already looked at the other similar questions, but they did not help me. I'm attempting to use GridSearchCV. I'm using three pipelines to predict nfl play data. It works pretty well until the grid search part.
Here is my code.

```
pipe_nfl1_1 = Pipeline([
        ('ssc', StandardScaler()),
        ('lr', LogisticRegression(random_state=42))
])
pipe_nfl1_2 = Pipeline([
        ('mms', MinMaxScaler()),
        ('rfc', RandomForestClassifier(random_state=42))
])
pipe_nfl1_3 = Pipeline([
        ('mms', MinMaxScaler()),
        ('svc', svm.SVC(random_state=42))
])
pipelines1 = [pipe_nfl1_1, pipe_nfl1_2, pipe_nfl1_3]
pipe_dict1 = {0: 'Logistic Regression', 1: 'Random Forest', 2: 'SVC'}
for pipe in pipelines1:
    pipe.fit(X_train1, y_train1)
print('Pipeline test accuracy for predicting 1st downs:')
for idx, val in enumerate(pipelines1):
    print('    %s: %.4f' % (pipe_dict1[idx], val.score(X_test1, y_test1)))
best_acc1 = 0.0
best_clf1 = 0
best_pipe1 = ''
for idx, val in enumerate(pipelines1):
    if val.score(X_test1, y_test1) > best_acc1:
        best_acc1 = val.score(X_test1, y_test1)
        best_pipe1 = val
        best_clf1 = idx
best_acc1 *= 100
print('Classifier with best accuracy for predicting 1st downs is %s with %.2f' % (pipe_dict1[best_clf1], best_acc1) + '%')
param_grid1 = {
        'lr__n_estimators': [2, 4, 6]
}
grid_search1 = GridSearchCV(pipe_nfl1_1, param_grid1, cv=2) 

# fine-tune the hyperparameters
grid_search1.fit(X_train1, y_train1)

# get the best model
final_model1 = grid_search1.best_estimator_
grid_search.best_score_
```

But I'm getting an error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-6b0007d9b8f1> in <module>
      2 
      3 # fine-tune the hyperparameters
----> 4 grid_search1.fit(X_train1, y_train1)
      5 
      6 # get the best model

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
     70                           FutureWarning)
     71         kwargs.update({k: arg for k, arg in zip(sig.parameters, args)})
---> 72         return f(**kwargs)
     73     return inner_f
     74 

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py in fit(self, X, y, groups, **fit_params)
    734                 return results
    735 
--> 736             self._run_search(evaluate_candidates)
    737 
    738         # For multi-metric evaluation, store the best_index_, best_params_ and

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py in _run_search(self, evaluate_candidates)
   1186     def _run_search(self, evaluate_candidates):
   1187         """Search all candidates in param_grid"""
-> 1188         evaluate_candidates(ParameterGrid(self.param_grid))
   1189 
   1190 

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py in evaluate_candidates(candidate_params)
    706                               n_splits, n_candidates, n_candidates * n_splits))
    707 
--> 708                 out = parallel(delayed(_fit_and_score)(clone(base_estimator),
    709                                                        X, y,
    710                                                        train=train, test=test,

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in __call__(self, iterable)
   1027             # remaining jobs.
   1028             self._iterating = False
-> 1029             if self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
   1030                 self._iterating = self._original_iterator is not None
   1031 

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in dispatch_one_batch(self, iterator)
    845                 return False
    846             else:
--> 847                 self._dispatch(tasks)
    848                 return True
    849 

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in _dispatch(self, batch)
    763         with self._lock:
    764             job_idx = len(self._jobs)
--> 765             job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb)
    766             # A job can complete so quickly than its callback is
    767             # called before we get here, causing self._jobs to

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\joblib\_parallel_backends.py in apply_async(self, func, callback)
    206     def apply_async(self, func, callback=None):
    207         """Schedule a func to be run"""
--> 208         result = ImmediateResult(func)
    209         if callback:
    210             callback(result)

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\joblib\_parallel_backends.py in __init__(self, batch)
    570         # Don't delay the application, to avoid keeping the input
    571         # arguments in memory
--> 572         self.results = batch()
    573 
    574     def get(self):

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in __call__(self)
    250         # change the default number of processes to -1
    251         with parallel_backend(self._backend, n_jobs=self._n_jobs):
--> 252             return [func(*args, **kwargs)
    253                     for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
    254 

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    250         # change the default number of processes to -1
    251         with parallel_backend(self._backend, n_jobs=self._n_jobs):
--> 252             return [func(*args, **kwargs)
    253                     for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
    254 

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py in _fit_and_score(estimator, X, y, scorer, train, test, verbose, parameters, fit_params, return_train_score, return_parameters, return_n_test_samples, return_times, return_estimator, error_score)
    518             cloned_parameters[k] = clone(v, safe=False)
    519 
--> 520         estimator = estimator.set_params(**cloned_parameters)
    521 
    522     start_time = time.time()

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py in set_params(self, **kwargs)
    139         self
    140         """
--> 141         self._set_params('steps', **kwargs)
    142         return self
    143 

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\metaestimators.py in _set_params(self, attr, **params)
     51                 self._replace_estimator(attr, name, params.pop(name))
     52         # 3. Step parameters and other initialisation arguments
---> 53         super().set_params(**params)
     54         return self
     55 

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py in set_params(self, **params)
    259 
    260         for key, sub_params in nested_params.items():
--> 261             valid_params[key].set_params(**sub_params)
    262 
    263         return self

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py in set_params(self, **params)
    247             key, delim, sub_key = key.partition('__')
    248             if key not in valid_params:
--> 249                 raise ValueError('Invalid parameter %s for estimator %s. '
    250                                  'Check the list of available parameters '
    251                                  'with `estimator.get_params().keys()`.' %

ValueError: Invalid parameter n_estimators for estimator LogisticRegression(random_state=42). Check the list of available parameters with `estimator.get_params().keys()`.
```

I've done LogisticRegression.get_params().keys() to get the keys, but it returns get_params() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'.

Comment: Update: I changed __n_estimators to __C and it worked

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have the leading underscores in the parameter names. You want your `param_grid1` dict to consist of keys that are actually parameters accepted by the model you're using. That would be `n_estimators` for RandomForest, and `C` for LogisticRegression. With that said, `n_estimators` is a parameter for the model `RandomForest`, but it's not a parameter for LogisticRegression. `C` is a parameter for LogisticRegression.

I think what you want to do is a grid search over the parameter space of the model that performs best, right? In that case, your `param_grid1` variable should be updated to the model that performs best. The parameters accepted by the models you're testing vary from model to model.